Use laptop as bootable usb for desktop
I have a work laptop that I would like to use on my desktop computer when working from home. However, my company has security to prevent logging into work accounts from unregistered devices and remote access to laptops.
I want to try plugging my laptop into my desktop via USB-C and then booting my desktop from the laptop drive. When I tried this, it didn't recognize the laptop as a bootable disk. Do I need to plug it into a different port or is it a problem with the drive format? I know I could just plug the disk drive directly into the motherboard, but I would like to avoid taking the laptop apart.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Laptops are USB host devices. They expect client devices such as USB sticks to be connected to them. They are not configured to act as client devices themselves.

If your just looking for the convenience of a larger monitor and keyboard, most laptops support external displays so just plug your monitor, keyboard and mouse into your laptop?

That's not really how it works. In theory some devices can act as drives or even HID Devices (aka gadget mode - some Raspberry Pi machines do that, as did some older macs over firewire) but you can't 'just' plug in an arbitrary laptop to a desktop and have it work as a bootable disk.

However, my company has security to prevent logging into work accounts from unregistered devices and remote access to laptops.

If it did work, its still an unauthorised device - and practically it would be the same as unplugging your laptop hard drive, and installing it into your desktop, which, if it did work, would kind of make certain security measures, like bitlocker pointless.
Practically - it won't work, putting in your work HDD or environment into a personal machine is a bad idea and you really shouldn't do this.
Depending on your needs (more power? Better displays) it may be worth looking at other ways to use your personal resources for work but what you want won't work, and your alternative of plugging in your laptop HDD directly might be a career ending event.
